# How to formally call an individual on a talkie walkie or other two-way radio

Tags: radio, militaire

I am looking for something which is probably a link to a version of French Radio etiquette.
(I have read [French radio communication language](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16614/french-radio-communication-language/16615) and its links.)

In watching "La Carte aux Trésors" I very often the hear the host (presently Hugo) saying "xyz pour Hugo" (where xyz is the competitor). This feels the wrong way round to me.

Should Hugo be saying "Hugo pour xyz" when calling a competitor?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There is one and only one question. It's the one with the question mark at the end. The remainder of the waffle is the supporting evidence that I've already tried to solve the problem myself and evade the inevitable flaming from admins that the question is stupid or displays no effort on my part.

Comment: @KDM It would be the wrong way around in a traditional radio conversation, but in that context the host coordinates the show and is 'above' the competitors (also literally, from his helicopter). "Candidat rouge pour Hugo!" can make sense if you understand it as "Candidat rouge please report to Hugo!" IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, the traditional wording used when A calls B is:

> *— A pour B (, à vous)*
> *— B, j'écoute*

or

> *— Ici A, message pour B, à vous*
> *— Ici B, j'écoute*

This is what trained people like the helicopter pilots use in *La carte aux trésors*. However, a different approach can sometimes be heard where the order is reversed. There is of course no issue when we know the names of the persons talking, and even less for the people in the party.

It looks to me more like a real conversation where the first person calls the second one by their name and then states who to reply to.

Or maybe the issue is just they use French *talkie-walkies* (as you wrote to my surprise) and not *walkie-talkies* ;-)

Comment: Yes. thank you. Now you mention it, I had recalled hearing it the correct way around, but on reflection, it was the pilots who were doing it right!

Comment: "talkie walkie" Yes. I'm a native English speaker married to a French native speaker. I do this quite a lot. :-)